# GCM with xtify. Doesn't register the device

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, xtify

I'm trying to implement push with Google Cloud Messaging. I make all the steps of http://developer.xtify.com/display/sdk/Getting+Started+with+Google+Cloud+Messaging but the device doesn't appear in Test Implementation. My appkey is Development.
I try with the example of xtify but I change the keys in the MainActivity of the example, XTIFY_APP_KEY, PROJECT_ID but I don't know how to send a push from this app. 
I enable notification. What must I do to do?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Here are a couple things you can do:

- Double check that your PROJECT_ID is valid.
- Make sure you enabled GCM in google API console.
- Make sure you copied the Google API key to the application you created in Xtify console.
- Implement [Xtify Notifier](http://developer.xtify.com/display/sdk/Advanced+Integration+Guide+for+Google+Cloud+Messaging#AdvancedIntegrationGuideforGoogleCloudMessaging-HandlingEventsandNotificationData) to get a callback when an error occurs in Xtify SDK.

Let me know if you need any more help.

Comment: Solved. I had to uninstall because it seems already registered but still not appear in Test implementation. And then Xtify Notifier answer onRegistered. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have search for an answer to solve the problem which descripted in this diskussion. So I follow the steps of the answer 2, but the android app didn't get a Xid since migrate to gcm.

Comment: This should be posed as a question and not an answer.